# Material UI Grid List item Spacing

Tags: reactjs, flexbox, material-ui

I am new to Material UI, but I would like to increase the spacing between the image tiles in the Grid List, I have followed the example in the Material UI documentation, and have searched Stack Overflow for similar examples, but haven't found the answer. Any help or direction to resources would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use the `padding` prop on the Grid List component:

```
<GridList
  padding={20}
/>
```

[Read more on this in the documentation](https://material-ui.com/components/grid-list/). Also, check out the code for the examples by clicking on the top right <> icon.

**Update**:
The new prop is called `spacing` now.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry I don't know how I overlooked that in the documentation.

Comment: Glad I could help. If my answer solved your problem, click the big checkbox to accept it as the answer.

Comment: This answer is no longer valid. The new prop is called `spacing`.

Answer (score 0):

### 2024 Answer

`TL;DR`: Use the prop `gap` of the ImageList instead.

`Details`: The marked answer is wrong and `gap` is the prop to adjust the spacing, as found in the latest [MUI React Documentation](https://v4.mui.com/components/image-list/#advanced-image-list). Similarly outdated is the comment stating that "spacing" is the way to solve the challenge.

`Example of use`:

```js
<ImageList rowHeight={200} gap={8}>
  {itemData.map((item) => (
    <ImageListItem key={item.img}>
      <img src={item.img} alt={item.title} />
    </ImageListItem>
  ))}
</ImageList>
```